# Quotation Marks: " vs. ''

Tags: texniccenter, keyboard

The quotes in the title are different: the first is one character, and the second is composed of two characters.

On a Windows machine, depending on the program I'm using, pressing '`shift +  quotation key`' gives either a specialized double quote (open quotes or close quotes) or a generic `"`, which is one character consisting of two little lines.

In TeXnicCenter, I can configure settings so that I get open quotes

> ``

or close quotes

> ' '

which are two characters, side by side, depending on context. This is appropriate for LaTeX use.

However, when using Asymptote, strings are entered between `"` marks. I can't use `''`, which is two separate characters. I can reconfigure TeXnicCenter to give those marks, but it is a pain to switch back and forth.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to give me the `"` symbol? It seems that this symbol is the `U+0022` symbol, but I don't know how to use that to my benefit.

Comment: I don't know anything about TeXnicCenter, but most editors let you add keyboard shortcuts in various ways.

Comment: In Emacs, C-q " overrides the automated `` and '' and gives you a plain ASCII double-quote. Not much use, as you're using TeXnicCenter, I'm afraid, but you're asking the right question, and something like this must surely exist in any decent editor.

Comment: What is Asymptote?